# Partitions not in metastore even though it's in the correct format

Tags: amazon-athena, partition

I'm trying to partition data by a column. However, when I run the the query MSCK REPAIR TABLE mytable, it returns error

**Partitions not in metastore:  radiusaccounting_quoted:dt=2023-06-30   radiusaccounting_quoted:dt=2023-07-01   radiusaccounting_quoted:dt=2023-07-02   radiusaccounting_quoted:dt=2023-07-03**

I already read how to create a partition in Athena and apparently the format I created is correct. I already read several questions with the same error but the solution did not solve my problem

I created the table by this query

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `radiusaccounting_quoted`(
  `eventtimestamp` string COMMENT 'from deserializer', 
  `acctstatustype` string COMMENT 'from deserializer', 
  `nastimestamp` string COMMENT 'from deserializer', 
  `nasipaddress` string COMMENT 'from deserializer', 
  `nasname` string COMMENT 'from deserializer', 
  `nasporttype` string COMMENT 'from deserializer', 
  `username` string COMMENT 'from deserializer', 
  `framedipaddress` string COMMENT 'from deserializer', 
  `calledstationid` string COMMENT 'from deserializer', 
  `callingstationid` string COMMENT 'from deserializer')
PARTITIONED BY ( 
  `dt` date)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde' 
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ( 
  'quoteChar'='\"', 
  'separatorChar'=',') 
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat' 
OUTPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
LOCATION
  's3://cdr-log/radius-csv'
TBLPROPERTIES (
  'transient_lastDdlTime'='1687268023')
```

Here's how the folders look in s3:
[image: folders in s3]